# Unable to make draggable box Andoid Studio, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, box, composable

I have code I want to add draggable box but it is not able to create draggable box, Something is missing in code

a code I want to make draggable box but in screen it show nothing

```
val state = rememberDraggableState()


Box(modifier = Modifier.draggable(
    state = state,
    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
    onDragStarted = { Log.d("Box", "Starting Drag") },
    onDragStopped = { Log.d("Box", "Finishing Drag") }
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to drag or move any element you need to set its Offset value so first you are missing it and then how to update and when to update it.

Let's break down the example

1. Define `offsetY` and set Initial value to `0f`
2. Define the `onDelta` method of `rememberDraggableState` and when drag stopped it will return a delta which we will used to add in current offsetY value and update it
3. Set the `composable` offset using the `offsetY` value

**Code**

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Stack011(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        val state = rememberDraggableState(onDelta = {delta->
        offsetY += delta
    })

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .offset { IntOffset(0, offsetY.roundToInt()) }
            .background(color = Color.Red)
            .draggable(
                state = state,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                onDragStarted = { Log.d("Box", "Starting Drag") },
                onDragStopped = { Log.d("Box", "Finishing Drag") }
            ))
    }
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]